# How to set different width to Google Maps template when in mobile mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

How can I set different width to Google Maps template when in mobile mode?Its fits perfectly my desktop mode  but when in mobile mode its over floats the screen size.

Here is my code:

```
@section ('map')  
<div id="map"></div>  

<script>
    function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 32.063256, lng: 34.776371};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 18,
            center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyByM5NtgUPSOLQg_oX_7LgEwEX5XyYO3zI&callback=initMap">
</script> 

@endsection
```

My CSS:

```
#map {
        height: 280px;
        width: 500px;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use either 600 or 780 `max-width` with the `@media screen` to do all my responsive designs. I allows you to overwrite your default CSS on different screen widths.

```
#map {
    height: 280px;
    width: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #map {
        height: 140px;
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```